# Laravel 5 GET inside controller?

Tags: php, laravel, post, controller, get

I use Laravel5 and i cant understand why **post**Process or **get**Process not works?

Example::

html page:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'portfolio/process')) }}
   {{ Form::submit() }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

route:

```
Route::resource('portfolio','PortfolioController');
```

controller:

```
    public function postProcess (){
       return 'Text!';
    }
```

Every time i get error: 
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

Comment: Use `route::controller() ` instead of `route::resource() `

Comment: @itachi `::controller` was removed from Laravel, you can't use it anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because [`Route::resource`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers) doesn't build these routes and you need to explicitly define them:

```
Route::post('portfolio/process', 'PortfolioController@postProcess');
```

Comment: But maybe i can use another method? If yes.. can you write example?

Comment: You don't need an example if you don't understand how it works. If you want to use restful controllers in your app I'd recommend you to read or watch some good tutorial first to understand how these controllers work.

Comment: Actualy im watching tutorial, but he use old laravel.. Thanks for information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check your route list:

Run this command `php artisan route:list` in terminal and check your route.

Hope this work for you!